# If $f(x)=x^2+x+2$ and $g(x)=x^2-x+2$, how to prove that there is no function $ h:\mathbb R \to \mathbb R $ such that $h(f)+h(g) = g(f)$?

Tags: functions, function-and-relation-composition

I tried to substitute $f(x)$ & $g(x)$ in their places but didn't find a relation;
The function beginning bijective or surjective etc have nothing to do with our case I believe

$g(f(x))=x^4+2x^3+4x^2+3x+4$

[Here is a graph](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/ol9uyd02v9)

[image: Functions graph]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose that such a function existed.
Then, we would have, for all $x \in \Bbb R$, the identity:
$$h(f(x)) + h(g(x)) = g(f(x)).$$

Letting $x = 1$, we get
$$h(4) + h(2) = 14.$$

Letting $x = -1$, we get
$$h(2) + h(4) = 4.$$

The above two equations clearly lead to a contradiction.